# Getting confirmations on web3.eth.Contract events

Tags: web3js

I'm listening for an event emitted by a contract using `myContract.events.MyEvent([options][, callback])`. In ganache-cli, `callback` *seems to only* fire as soon as the event is detected, as opposed to after some number of confirmations.

I'd like to perform logic in that `callback` once the transaction has n confirmations. Even the returned `EventEmitter` only has `"data"`, `"changed"`, and `"error"` events, in contrast to the `"confirmation"` event on `methods.myMethod.send`.

Is there a way to wait for confirmations on events, or do I have to manually wait for n blocks and then check the receipt for the transaction hash?

Comment: Confirmations are given per transaction, not per event emitted within a transaction. You clearly have the option to specify `{fromBlock: x, toBlock: y}` in the `options` argument, so just use it wisely.

Comment: In either case, the fundamental difference between `myContract.events.MyEvent` and `methods.myMethod.send` is that the former is designated for past blocks, while the latter is designated for future blocks.

Comment: `toBlock` does not seem to be available anymore. It seems better practice to initialize a single `EventEmitter`, where the callback for each `event` returned uses a `setInterval` that polls for the latest block until it's 24 blocks ahead of the tx block, at which point it would be safe to assume confirmation. Or am I missing something?